# Gen2 memory growing unbounded in .NET Core container app

Tags: .net-core, garbage-collection

I have a .NET 6 app running on a linux container in AWS ECR. It's a no-frills app that just reads/writes data from a Postgres database.

Recently though my containers have started crashing about once a day with `System.OutOfMemoryException` exceptions. I don't have a ton of visibility into the running app, but I can see memory information in App Dynamics (instrumentation software for those who are unfamiliar).

I'm not running out of actual memory (they crash when about 1.5GB of the 8GB container size is allocated). But what jumps out right away is my Gen2 memory just grows and grows. Gen0, Gen1, and Large Object heap go up and down which is what you would expect.

If Gen2 memory is not being garbage collected, that would imply that I have objects that the GC still thinks are reachable correct? What would make an object stick around like that for so long, especially in a stateless app like this? Literally all it does is run LINQ queries and returns results.

For reference here is what my memory usage looks like

[image]